# SHGetFileInfo performance issues

Tags: c++, windows, icons, windows-shell

Here is an excerpt from the Windows documentation about the `SHGetFileInfo()` function:

> You should call this function from a background thread. Failure to do so could cause the UI to stop responding.

Does this apply to extracting the folder icons as well?

One of our applications resembles Windows Explorer, and we pursue two antagonistic goals: to support as many Windows Explorer's features as possible, and to be as fast as possible. Having the latter in mind, I assigned to each folder the default icon (obtained with the help of the `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` flag). But after some time it turned out, that a few of our customers use custom folder icons.

So, should I create new threads to calculate the icon for each folder, or is there a way to quickly extract a folder icon in the main thread, given the fact that the number of custom folder icons is negligible?

For example, a way to retrieve only cached icons could be a solution, I think. There is a function `IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage()`, which allows to obtain only cached icons, but it unfortunately returns `HBITMAP` instead of `HICON`.

Comment: The thing is that the folder can be situated on remote or extremal drive so extracting icon may take significant amount of time (several seconds). So if this application is supposed to be restarted frequently it would make sense to collect icons in background instead of blocking main thread.

Comment: @VTT, Yes, but if there was a possibility to instruct the shell to get only cached icons, it could be a solution. And if the icon is not in the cache, I would take a default icon. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: `IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage` does this (though it may block as well). I'm not sure why would you need specifically `HICON` though. Even if you need it you can always create it from bitmap.

Comment: @VTT, I suppose that with flag `SIIGBF_INCACHEONLY` it shouldn't block, isn't it?

Comment: I guess it means that it won't try to access specified location, but it will need to access thumbs.db or wherever cache is stored which may still block.

Comment: @VTT, That is a bad news. Regarding HICON: the icon is created and cached in a COM Server DLL and may be used in various places. The interface requires HICON.

Comment: Not all displayed "icons" in the explorer are in fact stored as underlying HICON (small previews, folders, etc.). SHGetFileInfo is an old thing (not all items in the explorer are "files", and the Windows icon concept is kinda obsolete). So IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage is the modern way to go. You *could* convert HBITMAP to HICON (but instead I suggest to change your program if you want to resemble explorer)

Comment: @SimonMourier, But what about @VTT note, that even with `SIIGBF_INCACHEONLY` flag the `IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage` can block? I want to avoid additional threads not because they are difficult to create, but because they require a system of pending notifications to be developed.
And the second: could you please give me a hint how icon can be created from bitmap? Icons contain some additional information that bitmaps haven't...

Comment: You can use CreateIconIndirect.

Comment: If you want to resemble Windows Explorer, have a look at `IExplorerBrowser`. It already implements almost everything of an Explorer view, except the navigation bar and status bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I found an appropriate solution.
First of all, I prepare and store a pair containing the default folder icon and its index in the system image list. Then, when the request for a folder icon arrives, I immediately return the default icon, and launch a thread from the Windows thread pool.

In the launched thread I calculate the actual folder icon and its index with the help of the SHGetFileInfo API. If the index is the same as index of the default icon, I destroy the icon. Only if the obtained index differs from the default icon index, I post notification to the control in the main thread.

In this way the control is notified only about folders that really have custom icons, and the main thread is not overburdened with redundant notifications.